# web.config rewrite condition with exception

Tags: php, wordpress, iis, web-config, url-rewriting

I have two file web.config from wordpress setting like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
                <rule name="wordpress" patternSyntax="Wildcard">
                    <match url="*"/>
                        <conditions>
                            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true"/>
                            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true"/>
                        </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php"/>
                </rule></rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

I want to add some exception like if in folder wordpress, that rule is not running.

In my case, I have 2 wordpress installed with setting->permanentlinks->Post Name, 1 in root directory (http://example.com/) and other in /wordpress (http://example.com/wordpress) directory.

The second wordpress (/wordpress) I change web.config rule name="wordpress2" and it work, but if I want to view sample-page (http://example.com/wordpress/sample-page) than the page redirect to 404 Page Not Found.

Answer (score 1):

**Change match url showing below, hope this will help.**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="Main Rule" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="^(.*)/$" />
            <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```